# How can I add a cell's contents to another cell and then automatically delete the contents of the original cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet to keep track of points in a class. I want to have a cell for each class that I can type a number of points into, and that number will be added into a corresponding cell in the row below it. Then I want the first cell to empty itself so that I can add more points in and repeat the process whenever I need to. The second cell (the one in the row below) should keep a running total of all the numbers entered into the original cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a script, for example:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.rowStart == 2) {
    var below = e.range.offset(1, 0);
    below.setValue(Number(e.value) + Number(below.getValue()));
    e.range.clear();
  }
}
```

Here the watched range is the 2nd row (the condition `e.range.rowStart == 2`). If a number is entered there, then it's added to the content of the cell below, and the cell itself is cleared.

Using `Number` to avoid string concatenation 2 + 2 = 22 instead of addition.

---

Same for rows 2 and 6:  the notation `||` means OR:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.rowStart == 2 || e.range.rowStart == 6) {
    var below = e.range.offset(1, 0);
    below.setValue(Number(e.value) + Number(below.getValue()));
    e.range.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! How can I make it so that Row 6 works the same as Row 2 here? This may sound dumb, but I copied the code twice and changed the number, but then only 6, not 2, functions right.

Comment: You are so great, Alex, thanks. I'd love if you could look at another of my questions. It was flagged as a duplicate, but I don't know how to tailor the duplicate's answer to my own needs. The question is here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/107910/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-a-cell-based-on-another-cells-contents-in-google-s?noredirect=1#comment94722_107910

Comment: I see now that I'd like to use the script above in just columns B-F. How can I amend the script for that purpose?